# How put some objects (array of objects) to cover other object with its shape and curvature

Tags: mesh

I am very new to blender so forgive me please. I am trying to model a glock for practice since...couple of days. Starting again and again making some progress, using new more efficient features etc in a model. However I faced a problem which I can't solve.

I am trying to model a gun handle, to be precise-a grip part of handle.
So far I created a small grip part and I made 2 arrays in both axis.

I would like to shape the whole array so it will follow the curvature and shape of handle and I would like to mask/limit array size/iterations to the shape of handle. Is it possible?  It looks like this[image]

So how to "cover" the part of handle (describing the final shape of grip cubes array) with grip cubes? Or how to limit/mask grip cubes so they take a shape of the handle part in the back?I would appreciate your advice.

Reference handle part image:

[image]

Comment: There are better methods of doing this in blender, if the mesh of the grip is well balanced, you can add a particle system to the grip, set emission start and end time to 1, and use the object you want to place  as particle object, set distribution to vertices, an instance of the distributed object will be positioned on each vertex of the grip. There are other methods too, but all depends on the reference you're using for the grip, try to attach a reference photo to your question.

Comment: Thank You, I'll try with particle then, however it is just not intuitive for me ( i am used to PS and 2D graphics :). I though that one mesh could just follow the curvature of other mesh like in curve modifier etc but with whole plane.

Comment: I didn't say it's not possible, you can use shrink wrap, using a surface, then extrude the parts you need to, after applying shrink wrap, there are too many ways to achieve the same, particles is one of them.

Comment: I tried with particles...for sure it needs some tweeking from my side but i got the idea. It took me some time but well i got almost the effect I would like to achieve. Ofc at this level of experience its far from perfect...I have no idea how to put an image of my result in a comment box.

Comment: You can't put an image as a comment in BSE, anyways, I answered your question using another method, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another option to do the task I ask about. I think it could be done with boolean mofidier. On the other hand I can't do it without applying 2 x array before (beginner)[image: boolean intersect]

Maybe there is a way to keep array midifiers but as a beginner I am not aware about it. Correct me if my approach is wrong.

Comment: Please explain more about this method in your answer, otherwise ppl searching for this won't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to achieve the same, one of them is using particles, if the mesh of the grip is suitable, in case you don't want to use particles, here's one of the ways using **Shrink Wrap** modifier, since the object you're positioning is a simple object, this will work, in few words, delete all the faces in the object except for the face(s) that will touch the grip, apply the Array modifier, position the object in an orthagraphic view to the right place, add a Shrink Wrap Modifier, choose the grip as the target object, choose the method of Shrink Wrap that suits your case: Nearest Point, Project ...etc. Apply the Shrink Wrap modifier, in Edit mode Extrude the faces, while still selecting the new faces, use (Individual Origins) as Pivot center for rotation, scale the new faces, and your done. Following are the detailed steps:
1- I'll refer to **obj#1** to **the grip**, **obj#2** to the **object to be positioned**.
2- Select obj#2, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to Edit mode, select the base (the face that will be touching obj#1, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection, and delete the other faces. You'll end up with obj#2 as an array of planes.<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to object mode.
3- Apply the Array modifier.
4- Place obj#2 properly in an Orthographic view to fit the desired area on obj#1, use Numpad <kbd>5</kbd> to set the viewport to orthographic view.
5- Still in Object mode, obj#2 still selected, add **Shrink Wrap** modifier, choose obj#1 as the target using the eye-drop in the modifier interface, or choosing it from the drop down list.
6- Choose the **projection method** that suits you better in the Shrink Wrap modifier panel.
7- You can still transform obj#2 using <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> to fit better it's position on obj#1.
8- When sure that the position is appropriate, apply Shrink Wrap modifier. It's a good idea to **copy** obj#2 using <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> , move it to another layer using <kbd>M</kbd> before you apply the modifier, just as a back up. 
9- Selecting obj#2, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle Edit mode, press <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to select all faces, press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude the faces.
[image]
10- While still in Edit mode, new faces are selected, Choose **Individual Origins** as the **Pivot Center for Rotation/ Scale**, it's a small icon at the bottom of 3D View, Next to shading icon.
11- Press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale and drag to scale down the new faces.

Comment: Thank You very much for help. It worked and I learnt much more during  this (some new stuff around). The 2nd method provide nice result however I find that there is much less control after warp is applied. I am also not sure if object #2 parts are not distorted at the edge of warp (no a square section but rectangle from top view) if the obj #1 is curved.  Looks like particle is much more versatile and an experienced user is able to control everything. On the other hand at this stage I have no control at all on the particle section :) (10K options...).

Comment: You're most welcome. You're right about distortion and control, this is why I suggested particles first :) At the end of the day the method you should choose depends on your goals